# Python re to replace the subtitles with new formats

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a file with the following format:

```
===Subtitle 1===
text ....

===Subtitle 2===
text ....
```

How could I replace `===Subtitle 1===` with `Section Subtitle 1` using python?

I tried this:

```
import re

s = '===Subtitle 1==='
lst = re.findall('===[\S+a-zA-Z0-9]===', s)

print lst
```

But I cannot print out anything.

Comment: Start by writing some code.

Comment: Have you already tried anything yourself? We can help you if you're stuck, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: thanks.  i tried, but cannot even extract anything from "=== anything ===" using replace.

Comment: Show the attempt at least.

Comment: thank you, cannot print any thing.

Comment: You're missing an opening bracket in your character range.

Comment: Kevin gives the correct answer (use replace instead of a string), but your regex fails because you're not allowing for spaces in your character range (instead, you have `\S`, non-spaces, there; and the '+' probably doesn't do what you want it to do inside a character range.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.  I need more reading of re.  need a quick solution though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need use regex here, just use `str.replace()` like this:

```
>>> a = '===Subtitle 1==='
>>> a.replace('=', '')
'Subtitle 1'
>>>
```

But if you'd like use regex...

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('=+(.+?)=+', a)
['Subtitle 1']
>>> re.findall('=+(.+?)=+', a)[0]
'Subtitle 1'
>>>
```

Comment: thank you!  I'm trying to use re because the purpose is to keep what has been extracted for later use.